# how to combine two column values into one column value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datagridview, dataset

I have table(Title varchar,Description varchar).And I bind it to datagrid to use in windows application.But here i want to combine Title,Description and display the result in a single row-cell.
If I use like this

```
Select Names, 'myData' from emp
```

The output is:

```
Name1          myData
Name2          myData
Name3          myData
```

But, I need to display like this in a
Single column:

```
Name1
myData

Name2
myData

Name3
myData
```

and i want to bind it to datagrid.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT Names + char(13) + Description FROM emp
```

This will insert a newline between the two column values and return the result as a single column.

Comment: This is not what OP is asking. Work on your answer to avoid downvote.

Comment: @Adrian - he didn't specify if he wanted to transform at the database or application level.  Don't be snarky please.

Comment: @Adrian: He asked how to display data in a single column, with what looks like a newline in between the two table columns' values.  This is a perfectly legitimate way to implement such a feature.

Comment: I believe my mood has got you uneasy. I apologize, I should've been nicer. The solution is valid, yes. However, OP might want to "flatten" the two columns result, where two-columns x three-records results become a 6-records result. At least, that's what I understood.

Comment: @Adrian: That's entirely possible as well... that would probably require fiddling in the application layer, since the DB isn't very good about zipping up (interleaving) two sets of data.  The extra newline between the data in the OP's example leads me to believe that he wants three rows and not six, but if he clarifies to indicate six then I will definitely adjust my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine those column you have to do like following code

```
Select Name, Family, Name+ CHAR(13) +Family as FullName From Employee
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Names + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + 'myData' 
from emp
```

Will put it all in a single column for you at the DB level.

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest doing such conversion on data base layer, query should return table as long as it possible, so do it in application level, as a case using LINQ:

```
var transformedItems = items.Select(item => String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", 
                                         item.Name, 
                                         Environment.NewLine, 
                                         item.Description));
```